# Are the output functions of a continuous-time LTI system necessarily continuous (in the calculus sense) for any given input functions?

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, linear-systems, causality

Are the output functions of a continuous-time LTI system necessarily continuous (in the calculus sense) for any given input functions?

I had this question when I saw this claim in my textbook:

> for the most part we will use the condition of initial rest for
> systems described by differential equations. In the example, since the
> input was 0 for t < 0, the condition of initial rest implied the
> initial condition y(0) = 0.

$x(t) = 0$ if $t < 0$ -(initial rest)-> $y(t) = 0$ if $t < 0$

But to conclude that $y(0)$ itself is zero, $y$ needs to be continuous (at 0) given $x$.

Comment: The thing is really in the sentence fragment: "the condition of initial rest implied the initial condition y(0) = 0." You **define** your system to initially rest, and that very simply is defined as x(t) = 0 for t < 0, and y(0) = 0. It's a definition! You can't generalize a definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag `continuous-functions` made me interpret the question a bit differently, as nice and simple counter-examples have been given.

I consider here that a system is fixed, and may have some constraints in its conception. And that the inputs are not controlled and can be much wilder. Then basically, **if the impulse response on the system has a limied support, the output is continuous, only requiring mildly integrable inputs** (continuity necessary neither on inputs and nor on ystem). A concrete example: with a *time-bounded support LTI*, and inputs being *all functions having at most a finite number of discontinuities on a finite interval* (fairly what we have in practice), then all outputs have continuity.

Rephrasing; suppose that a continuous LTI system has an impulse response $h$ that is regular enough (integrable, continuous, differentiable, etc.), and that $f$ is any input in a large class of functions (at least with some integrability properties, like belonging to Lebesgue $L_p$ spaces, $p\ge 1$). We note $C^k$ the space of continuous functions with $k$ continuous derivatives.
Can we say something about the regularity of the convolution product (when it exists, hence the requirement about integrability) $h\ast f$?

The good news if that convolution does some "smoothing": convolution most often combines at best the regularity of $h$ and that of $f$. Here are a couple of results. I do apologize in advance for mistakes, did that quite long ago:

1. If $h\in L_1$ and  $f\in L_1$, then $h\ast f\in L_1$, and it is discontinuous in general. More generally, $h\in L_p$ and  $f\in L_1$, then $h\ast f\in L_p$
2. If $h$ has a compact support (classical for systems), and $f\in L^{loc}_1$ is locally integrable (e.g. integrable on every compact interval), then $h\ast f$ is continuous, which could be akin to your question. Note that *no continuity is set on $h$*: it can be made of boxcar or staircase functions
3. If $h \in C^k$ has a compact support  and  $f\in L_p$, then $h\ast f\in C^k\ \cap L_p$.

There are many other results of this kind, often more technical for us poor DSP folks.

Comment: Let's see! 1. follows from Hölder's ineq.: $\|h(t)f(\tau-t)\|_1 \le \|h(t)\|_2\, \|f(t)\|_2\le  \|h(t)\|_1 \, \|f(t)\|_1$, which is $<\infty \text {iff }h,f\in L_1$, right?

Comment: Indeed. I remember a more elementary proof with Tonelli/Fiubini

Answer (score 7):

Consider the identity system $y(t) = x(t)$. This system is LTI. If the input $x(t)$ is discontinuous, then the output $y(t)$ will be discontinuous too.

Comment: Indeed, silly me. :D If the inputs are continuous functions on a domain $D$, then I think we can say that $y$ will also be continuous on $D$?

Comment: Not in general, see Marcus' answer.

Answer (score 7):

To add an even worse example to MBaz (best possible) counterexample:

The derivative $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}$ is an LTI system. $f(t)=|t|$ is a continuous function.

$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(|t|)$ is discontinuous. The output of an LTI system can be discontinuous even when the input is continuous.

Comment: Nice example! ..

Comment: A sufficiently pedantic mathematician might point out that $t\mapsto |t|$ is not even differentiable at zero, and therefore cannot be fed into that LTI system in the first place. The standard nitpick-proof example would be $t \mapsto t^2\cdot\sin\tfrac1t$, which is (strongly) differentiable everywhere including zero, but whose derivative $t\mapsto2x\cdot\sin\tfrac1t - \cos\tfrac1t$ is discontinuous there.

Comment: @leftaroundabout good example! But: why should I not be able to feed anything non-differentiable into an LTI system in the first place? Especially since we typically characterize them through their *impulse* response.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, but mathematically that makes everything a bit more complicated – you need to clarify that you're not really talking about functions on $\mathbb{R}$ but rather elements of the $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ Hilbert space (whose elements are _equivalence classes of functions_), and that the derivative is to be understood in a weak sense (i.e. not as a limit of $\tfrac{f(x)+f(x+h)}h$, but rather as the equivalence class of functions $f'$ that obey the integration by parts rule). And then you again can't use $|t|$ as-is because it's not integrable over all of $\mathbb{R}$...